# Install to Intel NUC with onBoard 4GB eMMC

Tags: boot, 14.10, emmc

I'm just trying to install Ubuntu 14.10 onto an Intel NUC which has onboard 4GB eMMC storage and no other drives attached (Intel NUC Kit DE3815TYKHE).

I've managed to get a working model for a CentOS based distro, but not for Ubuntu as it appears that the mmc_core, mmc_block, sdhci and sdhci-pci are not enabled when booting from the install boot image. i.e. there is no MMC support enabled on the install ISO image.

I was wondering if anyone else had come across this and what they had done to fix it.

Many thanks in advance.