# missing driver during installation / mmc_block / mmcblk

Tags: drivers, system-installation, ubiquity, debian-installer, emmc

Just like "[Install to Intel NUC with onBoard 4GB eMMC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/542529/install-to-intel-nuc-with-onboard-4gb-emmc)":

I try to install Ubuntu Server 14.10 AMD64 on a notebook containing no hard drives (even SSD) but just an [(e)MM-Card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MultiMediaCard#eMMC). Windows works fine with it ;-(

The `debian-installer` / installation kernel doesn't recognize the (e)MMC. So then there are no drives shown and there is no way to partition any disk.

Using Ubuntu Desktop 14.10 AMD64 shows other difficulties. The (e)MMC is known by the live system. `ubiquity` is able to partion the (e)MMC, but it installs just the desktop system without having the features of the `debian-installer`...

Is there a way to add the kernel module while installing with `debian-installer`?

It shows an option named "`Detect virtual driver disks from hardware manufacturer`". But in which structure or representation shall it be?

Screen shot of debian-installer

[image]

Maybe someone will help...

Comment: I've successfully installed 12.4 on a machine with eMMC, but have had a serious booting problem, see my question at https://askubuntu.com/questions/578039/udev-and-emmc-rpbm-partitions. See also https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1333140