# udev and eMMC rpbm partitions

Tags: kernel, acer, udev, emmc, mmc

I'm running into this bug: 
[Fix udev rules to consider mmc rpmb partitions](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udev/+bug/1333140)  and trying to solve it using a udev rule. I haven't needed to learn anything about udev in the past, so have been reading up on it.

`uname -a` produces

> :~$ uname -a
>   Linux acer 3.13.0-44-generic #73~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed
>   Dec 17 00:38:38 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

What I've done:

1. In an attempt to get the kernel to abandon its attempts to read the rpbm partition, copy **/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules** to new file
   **/etc/udev/rules.d/61-persistent-storage.rules**
2. added this text to 61-persistent-storage.rules

   **KERNEL=="mmcblk[0-9]rpmb", SUBSYSTEM=="block", GOTO="persistent_storage_end"**

   3. Rebooted

(My full 61-persistent-storage.rules file is [in this paste.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9882709/))

Observation: the error message persists, the syslog file has multiple loops of the following:

> Jan 26 14:02:10 acer kernel: [   10.118467] mmcblk0rpmb: error -110
>   transferring data, sector 8064, nr 8, cmd response 0x900, card status
>   0xb00
>
> Jan 26 14:02:10 acer kernel: [   10.118474] mmcblk0rpmb:
>   retrying using single block read
>
> Jan 26 14:02:10 acer kernel: [   10.120516] mmcblk0rpmb: timed out sending r/w cmd command, card status 0x400900
>
> Jan 26 14:02:10 acer kernel: [   10.122552] mmcblk0rpmb:
>   timed out sending r/w cmd command, card status 0x400900
>
> Jan 26
>   14:02:10 acer kernel: [   10.124597] mmcblk0rpmb: timed out sending
>   r/w cmd command, card status 0x400900
>
> Jan 26 14:02:10 acer kernel: [  10.126641] mmcblk0rpmb: timed out sending r/w cmd command, card status 0x400900
>
> Jan 26 14:02:10 acer kernel: [   10.128673] mmcblk0rpmb:
>   timed out sending r/w cmd command, card status 0x400900 Jan 26
>   14:02:10 acer kernel: [   10.130710] mmcblk0rpmb: timed out sending
>   r/w cmd command, card status 0x400900
>
> Jan 26 14:02:10 acer kernel: [
>   10.130715] end_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0rpmb, sector 8064
>
> Jan 26 14:02:10 acer kernel: [   10.130720] Buffer I/O error on device
>   mmcblk0rpmb, logical block 1008

Question: do I need the '*for issue 2*' line referred to in the bug report? I think it's specific to a Tegra processor and my machine has an Intel Celeron?

Any help gratefully received. Thank you.

(A Datasheet for my machine is  [here](http://www.acer.co.uk/ac/en/GB/content/model/NX.MRSEK.001)).

Comment: I have no idea about root cause but one note about the rules file naming, you should copy it to `/etc/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules` I mean with same name as your aim is to override it. As your current setup, udev will load both, apply 60- before 61-, and your modification will have no effect.